# How can I disable all infinte timeouts for systemd units?

Tags: systemd

This is no bashing. I am aware that there are good reasons for infinit systemd unit timeouts, I just can't use them in *my* setup.

Today, redis crashed on my home server, including a kernel ooops. I took the lazy route, logged in via ssh, and tried to reboot my server and then waited for it to come back again, yet it didn't. So I had to go all the way to the attic, attach a screen and see that systemctl was waiting to stop the *redis* service, timeout: infinit.

So in my case, it is an anti feature that bugged me already several times.

How can I disable all infinit timeouts for systemd units on my server?

Comment: I don't have an answer for the infinite timeouts, which I have also seen. Next time, from ssh you can try `sudo systemctl reboot -ff` to directly do a kernel syscall of reboot, but this will not do any unmounts. Also, if your hardware has a watchdog device, see `man watchdog` about possibly using it. For remote servers, consider moving the console to a serial port, or using a IP-KVM to access the machine remotely.